# Check the difference between two apt packages

Tags: apt, python, jupyter

Is there any mechanism to check the difference between two packages?

Use case:
I'd like to install `jupyter` notebook but searching `apt` for jupyter returns plenty of hits (see below). How can I tell which is the one for me and how do they differ?

```
kretyn@junkyard$ apt-cache search ^jupyter
jupyter-qtconsole - Jupyter - Qt console (binaries)
python-jupyter-client - Jupyter protocol client APIs (Python 2)
python-jupyter-client-doc - Jupyter protocol client APIs (documentation)
python-jupyter-console - Jupyter terminal client (Python 2)
python-nbconvert - Jupyter notebook conversion (Python 2)
python-nbformat - Jupyter notebook format (Python 2)
python-nbsphinx - Jupyter Notebook Tools for Sphinx -- Python
python-nbsphinx-doc - Jupyter Notebook Tools for Sphinx -- doc
python-notebook-doc - Jupyter interactive notebook (documentation)
python-qtconsole - Jupyter - Qt console (Python 2)
python-qtconsole-doc - Jupyter - Qt console (documentation)
python3-jupyter-client - Jupyter protocol client APIs (Python 3)
python3-jupyter-console - Jupyter terminal client (Python 3)
python3-nbconvert - Jupyter notebook conversion (Python 3)
python3-nbformat - Jupyter notebook format (Python 3)
python3-nbsphinx - Jupyter Notebook Tools for Sphinx -- Python 3
python3-qtconsole - Jupyter - Qt console (Python 3)
jupyter - Interactive computing environment (metapackage)
jupyter-client - Jupyter protocol client APIs (tools)
jupyter-console - Jupyter terminal client (script)
jupyter-core - Core common functionality of Jupyter projects (tools)
jupyter-nbconvert - Jupyter notebook conversion (scripts)
jupyter-nbextension-jupyter-js-widgets - Interactive widgets - Jupyter notebook extension
jupyter-nbformat - Jupyter notebook format (tools)
jupyter-notebook - Jupyter interactive notebook
jupyter-sphinx-theme-common - Jupyter Sphinx Theme -- common files
jupyter-sphinx-theme-doc - Jupyter Sphinx Theme -- documentation
python-jupyter-console-doc - Jupyter terminal client (documentation)
python-jupyter-sphinx-theme - Jupyter Sphinx Theme -- Python
python-nbconvert-doc - Jupyter notebook conversion (documentation)
python-nbformat-doc - Jupyter notebook format (documentation)
python-notebook - Jupyter interactive notebook (Python 2)
python3-jupyter-sphinx-theme - Jupyter Sphinx Theme -- Python 3
python3-notebook - Jupyter interactive notebook (Python 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get more information about a package use the `show` option.

```
apt show jupyter
```

It's the only way to clearly see the differences between packages.

Another approach could be to use a GUI program as synaptic